# DRYing up a helper: wrap form_for and access local form variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scope, block, dry, form-for

I am trying to DRY up a bunch of forms code that has a repeating set of fields appearing at the end of each form. I wrote a helper that wraps around the form_for rails helper. But I'm starting to get lost in all the different scopes that are flying around...

My helper goes something like this:

```
def simple_form_helper(record_or_name_or_array, *args, &proc)
    options = ... # overriding some options, not relevant
    form_for(record_or_name_or_array, *(args << options.merge(:option => "blah")) , &proc)

    # i wish to access  &proc and append the call to render 
    # to within &procs scope (to access block local variable)
    concat render('shared/forms/submit')     # this obv does not work

end
```

in shared/forms/_submit.erb i have bunch of fields and submit buttons that are common to a bunch of models. So I want this to be rendered from within form_for's scope so that there is access to f.

```
 f.text_field :foo
 f.hidden_field :bar
 f.submit "Save"
```

The idea is to use it like so in the views:

```
simple_form_helper :object do |f|
  f.text_field :name
  f.text_field :description
  f.text_field :other_field
  # want common fields and submit button appended here

  # I could just call render("shared/forms/submit") here
  # but that does not seem very DRY. Or am I too unreasonable?
end
```

So it functions like the good old form_for: makes a form for some :object with fields specific to it. And then appends the partial with fields that are common across a bunch of models.

Is there a way to accomplish that? Perhaps, there's a better way?

Thanks!

Comment: You could also have used a partial layout.

Comment: I did look at render with :partial and :laout... but was not able to pass form variable to make it work. Post an example if you can. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pretty sure this would work

```
def simple_form_helper(record_or_name_or_array, *args)
   options = ... # overriding some options, not relevant
   form_for(record_or_name_or_array, *(args << options.merge(:option => "blah"))) do |f|
       yield f if block_given?
       concat f.text_field :foo
       concat f.hidden_field :bar
       concat f.submit "Save"  
   end
end
```

and you can also call `simple_form_helper :object` without a block if you don't need to add any fields

Comment: Now that I see it, so obvious :). The only thing is to add `concat` before each form helper call past the yield. Or it doesn't get returned. E.g. `concan f.text_field :foo`. Thanks!

Comment: oh right helpers have all that crazy concat stuff going on, glad it helped! I will edit the answer so that it is correct

Comment: Yeah trips me up all the time. AFAIK, rails 3 makes it much easier and consistent. But this is a rails 2.3.x app that I'm maintaining.

Answer (score 3):

You could also have used a partial layout, here is the syntax for reference.

Layout partial:

```
<%= form_for(record_or_name_or_array, :class => my_local_variable) do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :some_field %>

  <%= yield f %>

  <%= f.submit "Save" %>
<%- end %>
```

Template or partial where to use layout:

```
<%= render :layout => "partial_layout_name", :locals => {:my_local_variable => value} do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :more_fields_here %>

<%- end %>
```

Comment: can you take a look at my problem, please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598203/ruby-on-rails-pass-reference-to-yield-template   Pretty much similar, but I don't know what to do ...