# Using form_for formBuilder defined in template during rendering a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates

I try to create a generic template including a **form** that has dynamic content, e.g. defined by the view using the template. (My current impl. fails as the view complains during rendering that **f** (the formbuilder) is not defined.

[Rails 1.9.6]
My template called "LAY"

```
  <%= form_for @q_object, :url => request.fullpath do |f|%>
    <!--Do something that happens on every page --> 
    <table>
      <%= yield %>
      <tr><td style="text-align: center">
          <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
        </td></tr>
    </table>
  <%end%>
```

My view

```
<tr><td>
  <%= f.text_area :txt, :rows => 6, :cols => -1, :style => "width:100%" %>
 </td></tr>
```

My controller

```
class Controller < ApplicationController
  layout "LAY"
```

My Problem
During rendering the view rails complains that f (the formbuilder) is not defined.

Am I doing something wrong (obviously), but how can I stick to the implementation idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it is pretty simple:
just create **form_for** in the template and use **fields_for** in the view.
Fields_for gives you a formbuilder, but does not create the html-form...

```
<%=fields_for @q_object, nil, {:builder => MyFormBuilder} do |f|%>
      <%= f.text_area :txt, :rows => 6, :cols => -1, :style => "width:100%" %>
<%end%>
```

PS: I found NO way in passing parameters from the template to the view, like **<%= yield AweSomeParameter %>**...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to make this a layout? You could just make it a template and then have partial templates for each individual type of form you want. If you do that then you can render your individual partials like this and pass them to the form builder.

```
<%= render :partial => @unique_fields_name, :locals => {:f => f} %>
```

I would use partial templates, but if you really want to use a partial layout then checkout the second answer on [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511028/drying-up-a-helper-wrap-form-for-and-access-local-form-variable) question.  It explains how to setup a partial layout.  Also, [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#understanding-yield) has a great section on rendering layouts you should probably checkout.

Comment: whoops! you are right, I just edited my text so its not confusing but looks like you found your solution :) nice!